# Comparing BeautifulSoup results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm buying a house and I've built a BeautifulSoup scraper, which works like a charm - scraping the tags I need from our local real estate website. Now I just have to implement a mechanism which will notify me when there is a change on the website.

I need it to notify me once the new scrape output is different from the previous one - when the HTML changes.

```
previous_content = ''
URL = 'whatever.com'

while True:
    content = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    titles = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':['title']})
    years = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':['year']})
    sizes = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':['size']})
    prices = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':['price']})

    for titles, years, sizes, prices in zip(titles, years, sizes, prices):
        print('Location: ' + titles.get_text(strip="True") + '\n' + 'Year: ' + years.get_text(strip="True"), '\n' + 'Size: ' + sizes.get_text(strip="True"), '\n' 'Price: ' + prices.get_text(strip="True"))
        previous_content = new_content
    if previous_content == new_content:
        print("CONTENT NOT CHANGED. | " + str(today))
    elif previous_content != new_content:
        print("CONTENT CHANGED | " + str(today))
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: save this data in the database and write a program to check that if new data exist in the database

Comment: there are also services which monitor for website changes

Comment: You can subscribe to the RSS feed of the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a little mistake when assigning the `previous_content`

You should assign `previous_content` at the end of your while iteration, not before testing the equality with new_content, or it will always be `True`

Something like that should work (I cannot test)

```
previous_content = []
URL = 'whatever.com'

while True:
    content = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    titles = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':['title']})
    years = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':['year']})
    sizes = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':['size']})
    prices = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':['price']})

    new_content = [] # Initialize the new_content list
    for titles, years, sizes, prices in zip(titles, years, sizes, prices):
        content = 'Location: ' + titles.get_text(strip="True") + '\n' + 'Year: ' + years.get_text(strip="True"), '\n' + 'Size: ' + sizes.get_text(strip="True"), '\n' 'Price: ' + prices.get_text(strip="True")
        print(content)
        new_content.append(content)
    if sorted(previous_content) == sorted(new_content): # The list needs to be sorted as I expect the order to change but not the content
        print("CONTENT NOT CHANGED. | " + str(today))
    else:
        print("CONTENT CHANGED | " + str(today))
    previous_content = new_content # Assigning for next iteration of the loop
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, BlueSheep!